# PHP: how to insert dynamically retrieved data in database table

Tags: php, html, forms

I have retrieved data in a tabular form from database.

3 columns of table are retrieved from database and rest of two are drop down list and checkbox .

Now, i want to access data from the retrieved rows and insert into another table in database based on the checkbox selected, but as i have same name for all the checkboxes, i cannot.

```
for($row=0; $row<$res->num_rows; $row++){
    $record = $res->fetch_array();
    print "<table><tr>
<td>".$record["movie_id"]."</td>                                
<td>".$record["movie_genre"]."</td>
<td>
<select name='dayAccess'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkMovie' value='check'/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Not worth for an answer... use `<input type='checkbox' name='checkMovie[<?php echo $record['movie_id'   ];?>]' value='check'/>`. Further more put the `<table>` tags outside the loop. You do not want dedicated tables for each DB tupel.

Comment: @Mann, have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most **efficient way** to insert based on checkbox on or off is to take **array of element**,

We will take array of checkboxes for your task:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkMovie[]" value="<?php echo $record["movie_id"]; ?>">
```

After taking above element in form when you submit the form then at serverside (in your php code) you can get the checkboxes which are selected as below:

```
print_r($_POST['checkMovie']);
```

it will give you the **array of ids of movies which are checked** so you can insert that movie to your another table.

Comment: @Mann, It's my Pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates all the time the same code for checkboxes.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkMovie' value='check'/>
```

To make a difference distinguish the names using the ID from database, for example:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkMovie_<?php echo $record["movie_id"]; ?>' value='check'/>
```

Now you can access the value under unique name checkMovie_# in the retrieved set of data.